# Magento: Fully Configurable Products from Category View

Tags: magento, categories, product, configurable

Essentially, I am trying to get the product detail view in the list of products for a category. I have successfully been able to pull only the configurable options into the products list, courtesy of [Catgento and Inchoo](http://www.catgento.com/adding-configurable-product-options-to-category-list-in-magento/). The only issue with this solution is the price and images don't update like they do on the product detail page using this sweet [addon](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Matt+Dean/extension/596/simple-configurable-products).

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is quite complicated.

First of all, the product detail page loads "configurable.js" to connect the options and prices.

However, it won't work if just add the JS file. The variable "spConfig" is also required for every product. And mimic the way the product detail page connecting this variable to "configurable.js".

Then div for each product's price may change to .(Just add a class) That's because the function "reloadPrice" in "configurable.js" will be called when you change the configurable options. Referring to line.321, you will figure out.

Hope these are helpful to you.